# How to combine 2 or more live CDs into 1 multiboot DVD/USB

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, livecd

Just Curious, is there a tool or anything that helps in combining different Live CDs to make a master multiboot DVD, which later gives an option to boot on any of them, on choice?

Live CDs such as [Ophcrack Live CD](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/download.php?type=livecd), [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Download), [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) etc

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://www.hackfromacave.com/katana.html http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1518273 http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/one-cd-disk-multiple-linux-distributions-netboot-cd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Sardu](http://www.sarducd.it/) that should do what you want.
I have not used it myself, but was planning on testing it.